# How to fix box around content not showing?

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller

I'm trying to wrap multiple things within a box, namely a login feature. However when I've tried putting the content within it's own  but even after editing the css the actual changes don't show

I've tried both a .boxed method and a .box + .white (for background) method. Neither show any differences

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="box white">
            <h4>tbl_Gebruiker</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gebruikersnaam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gebruikersnaam, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gebruikersnaam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.wachtwoord, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.wachtwoord, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.wachtwoord, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And for the css:

```
.box {
      width: 800px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 2px black;
  }
  .white {
      background: white;
  }
```

What I expect to happen is that the login feature gets wrapped in a white box with a black border. What happens is well, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to see the border even after applying the `.box` class is that you haven't declared the [border-style](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp). So, a default value of **none** is taken which specifies no border.

As per the `Border` property syntax it accepts one or more of the following values in combination:

```
border:  <border-width> || <border-style> || <color>
```

And what you have specified is a `border-width` and `color` without the `border-style` for the border property which makes the `.box` class `border` property as: `border:2px black none`.

So, change the class `.box` from this:

```
.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px black;
}
```

To this:

```
.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

And you will be able to see the border.

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting your question right follow below css:

```
.box{
width: 100%;
height:100%;
border: 2px solid black;
background:white;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way that css

```
.white-box {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 0 0 35px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 4px 5px;
border: #eee solid 1px;
height: 100%;
```